# How can i remove these leaks? I have attached snapshot

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

[image]

I was running the instrument on device not on simulator.

Comment: Click first on the first leak. Your UIImageView leak and look for the responsible method. Check it closely and solve it. That should solve some other leaks.

Comment: We cant identify your problem.First Build+analyze and post the leaked line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the **Leaked Blocks** placed on the 2nd number from left.

It will show you how many times the particular object was `alloc`, `retain` and `released`
Also it will point the class in which you are retaining or allocating the object.

Double click the leaked object, it will take you to the leaking line number of your class.

Hope it helps.. :)